# Comparing German word with umlauts with same word with unicode

Tags: java, language-translation

I'm working on translating Strings from English to German, but German words that are already translated are being translated again.

Say I have this word "Beim Hinzuf\u00E4gen" which has already been translated. I want to compare this to the same word but with umlauts, "Beim Hinzufügen". Both files are read as ISO-8859-1, but when I compare the words they are seen as being different and the word is translated again which I don't want. Even when I replace the Umlaut with the unicode and compare the two, they are still seen as different. I'm sure this is because when I replay the umlaut by "\u00E4", there's an extra backslash being added in.

Anyone have an idea of the preferred method for what I'm trying to do.

Comment: It's not clear whether the Unicode escape you've included here is in the file or not, or how the file is being read. Please provide a [mcve] so we can help you.

Comment: Will add code, cheers!

Comment: aren't you suppose to compare `Beim Hinzuf\u00E4gen` with `Beim Hinzufägen`; notice the `ä` in the second string

Comment: Soory for the late reply. Eugene your absolutely right. Not only did I have the wrong unicodes mapped out but seems I was writing the file in UTF-8, which seemed to be getting the wrong Unicode which you pointed out. That has now fixed my problem, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Eugene points out, your result ist correct. You compare "Hinzuf**ü**gen" with "Hinzuf**ä**gen", which are different.

> Unicode 00E4 is "ä",
>   Unicode 00FC is "ü".

Comment: Thanks, I didn't even realise I had mapped the umlauts wrong.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that you need to compare these with a [`Collator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/Collator.html):

```
String left = "Beim Hinzuf\u00E4gen";
String right = "Beim Hinzufägen";
Collator c = Collator.getInstance();
c.setStrength(Collator.PRIMARY);

int result = c.compare(left, right); // 0
```

Comment: Turns out I had mapped the unicodes wrong. I've never heard of the Collator before so will read up on it never the less. Thanks.